# CouchDB query multiple keys startkey endkey

Tags: view, parameters, key, couchdb, coordinates

Hey Guys i'm trying to get a Point within a specific location from my CouchDB Database. I have absolutely no Idea how to build the query and the view.

In my Document, there is a value latitude and a value longitude.

I am building a quadratic bound latMin, longMin, latMax, longMax.
The view should return all documents where:

latitude is between latMin and latMax

and

longitude is between longMin and longMax

Thank you in advance

Edit: For this Project i am forced to use IrisCouch where i'm not able to install an extension. I have to solve it with key, startkey and endkey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the extension "[geocouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch)" which is specialized to do spatial queries.

Comment: Thank you for this Answer. The Problem is: For this Project i am forced to use IrisCouch where i'm not able to install an extension.

Comment: The extension geocouch is installed in iriscouch by default. The reason why it exists is - you can't design a couchdb index which lets you perform boundary requests as you want.

Comment: Thank you guys. Didn't know that it is already included. This helped me out!